# Use ANY method with Swagger 2

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to group all CRUD operations as ANY method in swagger 2?

I've looked at their docs [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) and [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/) and it doesn't look like there is. They allow grouping with tags only. I'm using swagger in the `body` of my CloudFormation template `"Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"` to provision a resource URL that takes all CRUD operations which in AWS that will be ANY.